# Find all analytic function on $\mathbb{D}$ satisfying a certain condition

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions

> Find all analytic functions on $\mathbb{D}$ s.t $f(\frac{1}{n})+f''(\frac{1}{n})=0$.

My attempt: Using uniqueness theorem, I'm looking for all analytic functions satisfying $f=-f''$. This implies that $f$ satisfies:$$f=f^{(4n)}=-f^{(4n+2)},f'=f^{(4n+1)}=-f^{(4n+3)}$$Expanding $f$ at $0$ gives: $$f=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^{n}=\sum_{4n}\frac{f^{(4n)}}{(4n)!}z^{4n}+\sum_{4n+1}\frac{f^{(4n+1)}}{(4n+1)!}z^{4n+1}+\sum_{4n+2}\frac{f^{(4n+2)}}{(4n+2)!}z^{4n+2}+\sum_{4n+3}\frac{f^{(4n+3)}}{(4n+3)!}z^{4n+3}$$

And rewriting gives: $$f=\sum_{4n}\frac{f(0)}{(4n)!}z^{4n}+\sum_{4n+1}\frac{f'(0)}{(4n+1)!}z^{4n+1}-\sum_{4n+2}\frac{f(0)}{(4n+2)!}z^{4n+2}-\sum_{4n+3}\frac{f'(0)}{(4n+3)!}z^{4n+3}$$

I wasn't able to get a clear description of all functions satisfying this. I do suspect that the functions $e^{iz},e^{-iz}$ span all functions satisfying these conditions, but I wasn't able to prove it. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: $f=f''$ is a linear autonomous ODE that can be solved for instance with the Ansatz $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$ to find a solution and then appealing to the Picard-Lindelöf existence and uniqueness Theorem to show that there is no other solution (we do not need to expand into a power series).

Comment: The ODE $f+f''=0$ is the harmonic oscillator. Do you really need to do all that to find its general integral? (There is no irony in my question, it is a genuine one)

Comment: Alternatively, gather your terms and get $$f(z)=f(0)\cos z+f’(0)\sin z.$$